# sharing objects in php

Tags: php

Kind of asking for your opinion more than asking a question with a definite right/wrong answer.

I'm fairly new to OOPHP I have done some OO programming in the past.  What I am having trouble getting my head round is the best way to share objects (or more their state) between pages.

I'm trying to avoid cramming lots of data into the $_SESSION and i don't like the idea of posting all the data in a form each page change either.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Thanks TT

Comment: If something should be shared, what's the problem with using a session? The other alternative is to reload the data on each page load but that's not always possible / best.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with OOP. Persisting data between page loads works the same regardless of programming paradigm employed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing at all wrong with saving "lots of data" in the `$_SESSION`. By doing this you are not at all increasing transfer size or anything so you're not affecting the client as `$_SESSION` is purely server-side.

> I'm trying to avoid cramming lots of data into the $_SESSION and i don't like the idea of posting all the data in a form each page change either.

As above, this is a non-issue, you're not "posting all the data in a form each page change", it's stored server-side in a flat file that is simply deserialized automatically when you reopen the session, and put into `$_SESSION`.

Provided that `$_SESSION`'s lifetime is enough for you, you should use it.

If you need something more persistent than a `$_SESSION`, for example you need to store an object against a user for the whole time that they're logged in, you can consider either serializing objects in a database and pulling them out on pageload, or simply recreating an object from values you store against the user.

Comment: Thanks Rudi,

I was just confirming what I believe to be true (that these were my only options)

Also i was concerned that thousands of users, resulting in potentially tens of thousands of objects being held in $_SESSION could have a detrimental effect on the servers performance.

Comment: @TraceyTun No problem, if you're looking for something that will work in a truly high-performance way, you could look into memory caches such as APC or Memcached :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I'm a noob on this site and have been slammed -4 for asking this question (not to sure why).  But you have confirmed my current methods are correct and that by continuing with them and not wasting days of my life using a second rate solution. Many Thanks.

Comment: @TraceyTun No problem again, I did put in a +1 and a reopen vote a while ago, not sure why it got slammed so hard as I think it's a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

As you know objects exist only between two http requests or cliks on the page, so you can save data you need either in $_SESSION/$_COOKIE, send it in $_POST/$_GET,serialize object and save it in DB, text file or whatever...AFAIK these are your only options with PHP

Comment: Okay, I was just checking to make sure that this was the case.